# Finding the property by value mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Have a question about finding nested property in mongoose. Can't find the right solution for my issue. Lets say I have Parent with properties: name, child. Same will go for every single child: name, child. Is there a possible way for example to find the value by entering just a name? If the nth children is at nth level with name "Tom" for this moment I have to go like children.name.children.name......

-Parent
-children
-children
-children

My schema looks like:

```
const TreeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: "String",
    unique: true,
    required: true,
  },
  children: [
    {
      name: {
        type: "String",
      },
    },
  ],
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

[request image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOvCy.png)

So the issue is that if I have nth child I can't just find him like this. I have to keep going deep every time like children.name : req....

```
router.post("/:parent/:child", async (req, res) => {
  let tree = await Tree.findOne({name : req.params.child})
  ]);
```

Comment: Is each child a separate instance of `TreeSchema`?

Comment: Uploaded image of my request. And every single new record will be going deeper and deeper in the children